# How to get the total number of photos of a friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the total number of photos of a friend because 
when I use

```
$photos = $friend_id.'/photos';
```

I am not getting the all the photos. For example if a friend has 600 photos I am getting only less number around 180 or something like that and after refreshing the page I am getting some more photos but not getting all the photos.

so I tried using

```
$photos = $friend_id.'/photos?limit=600';
```

and getting this following error

```
Notice: Undefined index: data in *\friends-photos.php on line 107
0
Notice: Undefined index: data in *\friends-photos.php on line 115

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in *\friends-photos.php on line 115

Notice: Undefined index: paging in *\friends-photos.php on line 132
```

the codes in the error lines are as follows

```
 $var = $dp["data"] ; ------107  
 foreach ($dp["data"] as $value) ---------115 
 $next_page = $dp["paging"]["next"]; --------132
```

Comment: Is this an api call to facebook or looping through your own data set?

Comment: The errors you’re getting are due to the previous operation not returning the expected data, but most likely an error itself – which you obviously don’t react to or care about in any way. You should try to write scripts that actually _check the success_ of operations before trying to handle their output, which might not be what you assume it is.

Comment: @CBroe can u tell me the exact code to get all the photo of friends without error 
while using this 
>>>>$photos = $friend_id.'/photos'; 
am getting only 289 photos but my friend has 608 photos

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use the `until` and `limit` fields or `limit` and `offset` fields

```php
if($user_id) {
    $the_photos = array();
    $friend_id = '4'; // user id

    $friend_photos = $facebook->api($friend_id."/photos");

    while ($friend_photos['data'])
    {
        $the_photos = array_merge( $the_photos, $friend_photos['data'] );

        $paging = $friend_photos['paging'];
        $next = $paging['next'];

        $query = parse_url($next, PHP_URL_QUERY);
        parse_str($query, $par);

        $friend_photos = $facebook->api(
            $friend_id."/photos", 'GET', array(
                'limit' => $par['limit'],
                'until'  => $par['until'] ));
    }

    echo count($the_photos);
}
```

I would like to imagine that the photo number you see on a friend's profile includes photos with certain privacy restrictions on it, so most likely it might not match with the number here.

For more info see

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

The 'photos' connections of a user id is "Photos the user (or friend) **is tagged in**."

In this case, you get the amount of photos that user was tagged in. Not the total number of photos in his albums.

---

And in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/

'owner' column is not indexable. So we can not select all photos by owner id directly.

Currently I could not find an easy way to get the total numbers of photos yet. What I could do is select all albums of the friend and walk through all albums to get the number of photos in each album. But it is really slowly......